# Extract the value from the C column if the F column contains specific text

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

So I would like to extract the data from a row if the column contains a specific word. So if Column F contains the word "FITNESS", I would like the names, numbers, start and end time of the corresponding rows to be copied over to another tab.

[Roster](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iQxYG.png) - "ROSTER"  TAB

[image]

[Headcount](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ss5eC.png) - "HEADCOUNT" TAB

[image]

So basically I want to extract the number, name, start and end time of each individual, into the correct part of the headcount tab. So in A3 I would end up with Ila Yokum and O3 her number, P3 her start time and Q3 her end time. In A4 Cherrie Errico and O4 her number. In A10 I would end up with Carlos Bigham. Etc. Etc.

I tried the following, but it doesn't copy over everything correctly.

```
=if(ROSTER!A:A="ACCESSOIRES";ROSTER!B2;"")
```

[Works for A3-A5 but not for A10?](https://i.stack.imgur.com/imjvA.png)

The roster would change on a daily basis, and more or less people of each section could be on the roster, as well as different starting/end times. However, the section and number is always linked to the person.

Any help is appreciated and thanks in advance,

Comment: Hi, what have you tried so far?

Comment: I have tried if functions aswell as vlookup, but I cant seem to even get in the right direction.

Comment: I tried =if(ROSTER!A:A="ACCESSOIRES";ROSTER!B2;"") but it doesnt seem to copy over everything.

Comment: @0m3r - https://i.imgur.com/x4nHCso.png is what it would look like for now. (ALS = IF in my language fyi), anyhow... somehow in that screenshot, A6 doesnt show, A10 doesnt work etc

Comment: Work with `INDEX` & `MATCH`

Comment: `=INDEX(ROSTER!$A$2:$A$20;MATCH("GROUND FLOOR";ROSTER!$F$2:$F$20;0))` Seems to work but if I drag it down it keeps copying the first name.

Answer (score 0):

You can try:

```
Option Explicit

Sub test()

    Dim i As Long
    Dim LastRowSR As Long, LastRowSH1 As Long
    Dim strSection As String, strNumber As String, strStart As String, strEnd As String, strName As String

    'Sort Table in Roster Sheet
    With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("ROSTER")
        .Sort.SortFields.Clear
        .Sort.SortFields.Add2 Key:=Range("F1"), _
        SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending, DataOption:=xlSortNormal

        LastRowSR = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

        With .Sort
            .SetRange Range("A2:F" & LastRowSR)
            .Header = xlNo
            .MatchCase = False
            .Orientation = xlTopToBottom
            .SortMethod = xlPinYin
            .Apply
        End With
    End With

    'Headers Formating
    With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("HEADCOUNT")
        .Cells.Clear

        With .Range("A1")
            .Value = "Headcount"
            .Font.Bold = True
            .Font.Color = -16776961
            .HorizontalAlignment = xlLeft
            .VerticalAlignment = xlBottom
        End With

        .Range("B1").Value = "06:00"
        .Range("C1").Value = "07:00"
        .Range("D1").Value = "08:00"
        .Range("E1").Value = "09:00"
        .Range("F1").Value = "10:00"
        .Range("G1").Value = "11:00"
        .Range("H1").Value = "12:00"
        .Range("I1").Value = "13:00"
        .Range("J1").Value = "13:30"
        .Range("K1").Value = "14:00"
        .Range("L1").Value = "15:00"
        .Range("M1").Value = "16:00"
        .Range("N1").Value = "17:00"

        With .Range("B1:N1")
            .HorizontalAlignment = xlCenter
            .VerticalAlignment = xlBottom
        End With

        With .Range("E1,J1,N1")
            .Font.Bold = True
        End With

        .Range("J1").Font.Color = -65281

        With .Range("O1:Q1")
            .Merge
            .Value = "Shift"
            .HorizontalAlignment = xlCenter
            .VerticalAlignment = xlBottom
        End With

        With .Range("O2")
            .Value = "Number:"
            .HorizontalAlignment = xlCenter
            .VerticalAlignment = xlBottom
        End With

        With .Range("P2")
            .Value = "Start"
            .HorizontalAlignment = xlLeft
            .VerticalAlignment = xlBottom
        End With

        With .Range("Q2")
            .Value = "End"
            .HorizontalAlignment = xlLeft
            .VerticalAlignment = xlBottom
        End With

        .Range("P2:Q2").Interior.Color = 65535

    End With

    'Loop Roster
    With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("ROSTER")

        For i = 2 To LastRowSR

            strName = .Range("A" & i).Value
            strNumber = .Range("B" & i).Value
            strStart = Format(.Range("D" & i).Value, "hh:mm")
            strEnd = Format(.Range("E" & i).Value, "hh:mm")
            strSection = .Range("F" & i).Value

            With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("HEADCOUNT")

                LastRowSH1 = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

                If LastRowSH1 = 1 Then
                    With .Range("A" & LastRowSH1 + 1)
                        .Value = strSection
                        .Font.Bold = True
                    End With
                    .Range("A" & LastRowSH1 + 2).Value = strName
                    .Range("O" & LastRowSH1 + 2).Value = strNumber
                    .Range("P" & LastRowSH1 + 2).Value = strStart
                    .Range("Q" & LastRowSH1 + 2).Value = strEnd
                ElseIf strSection = .Range("A" & LastRowSH1 - 1).Value Then
                    .Range("A" & LastRowSH1 + 1).Value = strName
                    .Range("O" & LastRowSH1 + 1).Value = strNumber
                    .Range("P" & LastRowSH1 + 1).Value = strStart
                    .Range("Q" & LastRowSH1 + 1).Value = strEnd
                Else
                    With .Range("A" & LastRowSH1 + 2)
                        .Value = strSection
                        .Font.Bold = True
                    End With
                        .Range("A" & LastRowSH1 + 3).Value = strName
                        .Range("O" & LastRowSH1 + 3).Value = strNumber
                        .Range("P" & LastRowSH1 + 3).Value = strStart
                        .Range("Q" & LastRowSH1 + 3).Value = strEnd
                End If

                .UsedRange.Columns.AutoFit

            End With

        Next i

    End With

End Sub
```